# How to set a default error page to users in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there a way in Laravel to show a nice error page to users if an error occurred while they were browsing ?
It could be a general message without any details, such as "Something went wrong, please try again in  a few seconds".
If something is there, I would like to know where to start.

Comment: You mean without debug code when something went wrong on server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question you don't want error with image of code where is error.

If that is a problem you can set in your `.env` debug to false `'debug' => false`.

Then you need to clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`.

And just restart your `php artisan serve`.

This should work. Please let me know if that isn't what do you want.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like to know how to edit this page. It currently shows : Whoops, looks like something went wrong. I want to edit it.

Comment: I m not sure but in your views try to find `500.blade.php` page or try to read [here](https://medium.com/@garethnic/catching-and-customizing-the-500-page-in-laravel-4b15b55feda6) more about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a custom message by edit `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

for example, if the error code is `500`, you can return a custom view like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
            return response()->view('partials.error_500', [], 500);
        }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

or you can check if the error is `instanceof` anything like this:

```
if ($exception instanceof ErrorException) {
        abort(500);
        or return view(...) 
        and so on ...
    }
```